# How can I return the step number [i] when a certain key-value pair is found in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Super NOOB to javascript, so I need some help trying to parse this JSON object and return a specific value.

So I have a JSON payload from an API Call that I've turned into an object (sorry, I still don't know how to line break this so it shows easily here on Stack Overflow):

```
var myObj = JSON.parse("{'ClassID':'1ghjk2345','ProcessName':'Workflow','Steps':[{'Id':'1234ghjhg102','Name':'Start','ActivityInstanceID':'12435r3ffe2'},{'Id':'134gbvgg102','Name':'attendance','ActivityInstanceID':'7865fdghd'},{'Id':'1jhgy102','Name':'lesson','ActivityInstanceID':'12gs5ghdse2'},{'Id':'1ghkb102','Name':'quiz','ActivityInstanceID':'1sgdtgt'},{'Id':'12fkfh02','Name':'evaluation','ActivityInstanceID':'1243sdfgssdfg2'},{'Id':'1khfhf02','Name':'dismissal','ActivityInstanceID':'124sdfgdfgrrrfe2'}],'TimeTaken':54838,'_id':'PK21342ffh','status':'Complete'}");
```

I would like to return the Step number in the Array that contains this key-value pair:

```
'Name':'evaluation'
```

I need this because the order of the steps changes for each payload - sometimes it's step 4, sometimes 2 depending on when the teacher initiates that step in the application.

I would then like to retrieve the 'ActivityInstanceID' of that step.

Comment: What happens when you attempt to run that `JSON.parse()`?  You get an error, right? Seems like you have plenty to work on here, and you should show your attempts. Start by thinking about how to properly quote a JSON property/value. Then consider how object properties are referenced in JSON. Then maybe how to "filter" or "find" objects in an array. When you get stuck, ask a very specific question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to change your data do fit json requirements.
Use variables names in lower case.

```js
var myData = JSON.parse('{"ClassID":"1ghjk2345","ProcessName":"Workflow","Steps":[{"Id":"1234ghjhg102","Name":"Start","ActivityInstanceID":"12435r3ffe2"},{"Id":"134gbvgg102","Name":"attendance","ActivityInstanceID":"7865fdghd"},{"Id":"1jhgy102","Name":"lesson","ActivityInstanceID":"12gs5ghdse2"},{"Id":"1ghkb102","Name":"quiz","ActivityInstanceID":"1sgdtgt"},{"Id":"12fkfh02","Name":"evaluation","ActivityInstanceID":"1243sdfgssdfg2"},{"Id":"1khfhf02","Name":"dismissal","ActivityInstanceID":"124sdfgdfgrrrfe2"}],"TimeTaken":54838,"_id":"PK21342ffh","status":"Complete"}');

for (let i = 0; i < myData.Steps.length; i++) {
    if(myData.Steps[i].Name === "evaluation") console.log("the step is: ", i);    
}
```